# dbatools - Copy all jobs to the other node - selected jobs only

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

Is it possible to copy all sql server agent jobs using dbatools from one node to another, except a particular job? or perhaps just copy a set of jobs?

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbaagentjob/) already do what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty about dbatools is that the source code is available on [github](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Copy-DbaAgentJob.ps1)

you can use `-ExcludeJob` parameter

> .PARAMETER ExcludeJob
>               The job(s) to exclude. This list is auto-populated from the server.